# Is there any default header file in GNU

Tags: c

When I am going through a code snippet I have seen some  functions like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

printf( "Upper case of a is %c\n", toupper('a'));
printf( "Upper case of 9 is %c\n", toupper('9'));
printf( "Upper case of g is %c\n", toupper('g'));
return 0;
}
```

being used in the source file without any header file being included. 
So is there any default header file that gets added to source when compiling. I am using GNU C.

Please don't mind if the syntax of the function is wrong as that is not the important point.

Comment: I don't think there's a default header that would define that without anything being explicitly included. You might be dealing with old code that doesn't expect prototypes before functions are used — pre-standard C, or thereabouts. `gcc -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` might help identify this.

Comment: `"toUppercase"` is a string literal.

Comment: Your question would be improved by showing an actual call rather than something that looks like a string literal.

Comment: *Please don't mind if the syntax of the function is wrong as that is not the important point.* -- The exact syntax can matter a great deal. Very minor changes in C code can radically change its meaning. If you show us C code, please be sure it's *exactly* the code you want to ask about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no implicit `#include` directives.

What you're probably running into is that, prior to the 1999 ISO C standard, C permitted functions to be called with no visible declaration. The compiler would assume that the called function returns `int` and takes arguments compatible with the (promoted) arguments passed in the call.

gcc by default supports the 1990 ISO C standard plus GNU-specific extensions.

If you compile with something like `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic`, you'll get warnings about calls to functions with no visible declarations. (Use `-std=gnu99` if you need GNU-specific extensions as well.)

Calling undeclared functions was a bad idea even before the 1999 standard. You should correct your code so there's a visible declaration (probably via a `#include` for the appropriate header) for each function you call or otherwise refer to.

Your original question asked about `toUppercase`, which is not a standard function; it may or may not be defined somewhere else.

Your revised question uses `toupper`, which is a standard C function declared in `<ctype.h>` and defined in the standard C library.

It's not surprising that you can get away with calling `toupper` with no visible declaration -- but you should still add

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

to the top of your source file.

Before you do that, try compiling with `gcc -std=c99`; you should get a warning.

One more thing: It's important to keep in mind that *headers* and *libraries* are two different things.

*Headers*, like `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` are generally text files containing just *declarations* of functions and other entities specified by the C standard library.

*Libraries*, which have system-specific names like, for example, `libc.so`, contain the actual executable code that *implements* those functions.

Headers are handled by the compiler; libraries are handled by the linker.

There are generally no default headers; every header you use has to be explicitly `#include`d, either directly or indirectly. `libc.so` (or whatever it's called) is typically linked by default; you don't have to specify it. (Though for the functions declared in `<math.h>`, you often have to specify `-lm` to link the corresponding library.)

Comment: So if it is calling undeclared functions according to 1990 when in compilation how does it know in which header file is declared and it does not include any header file then how is that function working as per the definition of the header file? Just curious to know how compiler resolves it. It is because if the same function is there in 2 different headers then what happens?

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla In this case, it becomes the linker's problem. It will give errors or warnings for when it cannot find a corresponding function in your code or a library.

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla: In C90, if you call a function with no visible declaration, the compiler creates an implicit declaration based on the call. If the call is incorrect, the compiler can't detect the error and the program's behavior is undefined. Any header file that happens to contain the correct definition is ignored unless you `#include` it.

Comment: @crashmstr: But the linker can't warn about calls with the wrong number or types of arguments (C compilers don't do name mangling). If you omit `#include <math.h>` and call `sqrt("hello")`, your first indication of a problem is likely to be when your program crashes or produces unexpected output.

Comment: @KeithThompson too used to working with C++, which does have linker validation of those things.

Comment: I got the point but as you said the compiler just adds the declaration and ignores the headers if they are not manually included then does compiler provides its own definition, I mean implementation of the declared function? Based on what it provides the implementation? I am seeing lot of examples on net without any headers.

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla: No, it provides an implicit *declaration* ,but it can't provide an implementation. In C90 mode, if you have a call like `no_such_function()`, the compiler will create an implicit declaration (which will assume the function takes no arguments and returns an `int`), but it will fail at link time because there is, as the name implies, no such function.

Comment: Ya your description looks great but the problem is i am able to compile and get the out put successfully. I am editing my post so look for the code i am able to compile and run successfully.

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla: Your original question asked about `toUppercase`. Your revised question asks about `toupper`, which is a standard function defined in the standard library.

Comment: I already have said that don't think for the exact syntax. So by your statement can i conclude like the standard library (stdlib.h) will be included by default?

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla: `stdlib.h` is a header file; it is not the standard library. The C standard library will be in a file called something like `libc.so`, though it will vary from system to system. Headers are included; libraries are linked. (I'm curious: why did you unaccept my answer?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41913/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-muralidhar-yaragalla)

Answer (score 0):

As forum people are asking not to discuss in comments so i have no other option than replying to " Keith Thompson" last post. I am not sure what you meant by c standard library. look here
[C standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)

It clearly says 27 header files are part of standard library and stdlib.h is one of them. See my point is not to argue with you. I am trying to have clarity in mind. You are saying something like libc.so as standard library but the wikipedia clearly states something else and now i am totally confused.